# Angular does not render custom component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an html file which looks like this:

```
  <div  class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <custom-button
        name="btnradio"
        id="0_0"
        text="0 - 0"
      ></custom-button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

THis component looks and works in other places without any problem but here on this component I am getting the following error:

```
NG0304: 'custom-button' is not a known element (used in the 'DailyTotalViewComponent' component template):
1. If 'custom-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'custom-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

But the module of the library which has the custom-button component exports it and looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    RouterModule.forChild([
      /* {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: InsertYourComponentHere} */
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [
    CustomButtonComponent
  ],
  exports: [CustomButtonComponent],
})
```

And my module where I want to use this imports this module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, CustomButtonModule],
    declarations: [TableViewComponent
    ],
})
```

Can anyone tell me what the error is? I can not find it

Comment: Is the component selector definitely `custom-button` and not something like `app-custom-button`? This is a common gotcha when creating components using the Angular CLI

Comment: I’ve noticed sometimes after creating new modules, the web server doesn’t rebuild them and hot reload correctly, so I need to restart the dev server.

Comment: @nate-kumar yes the selector is definitely correct

Comment: @BizzyBob already did it. Maybe it is important to say I am right now starting storybook and the components/library are generated with nx nrwl

Comment: If it is a library module, make sure it is exported also in the index.ts on the root of the library. This is the lib api, what exposes it to the outside word to be consumed.

Comment: I did export it in the index.ts of its library but still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

When working with library modules, the api is defined in the index.ts on the root or the library (my-lib/src/index.ts)

So, besides exporting it within the module like you already did, you should export whatever you want to expose to the lib consumers in the index.ts

```
export * from './lib/my-lib.module';
//components
export * from './lib/some-component.component';
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this put the line to export it under the ts of its lib (CustomButtonLib) but still getting the same error. I forgot to mention that these components are in seperate libs but I thought importing the module is enough

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was storybook, due to me only starting my component with storybook components from other modules were none existing, which makes sense. So starting the application normaly with npm showed me it worked as it should.